# How to build cppzmq on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmake, build, zeromq

I am trying to build cppzmq on Windows 10.
I have cloned the repo from: https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq

I generate the cmake files with the following command:

```
cmake -H. -BBuild -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=../libzmq/build/ -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=//w -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=/D_SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING  -DENABLE_DRAFTS=1 -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON
```

When I try to build the solution through Visual Studio, it says 3 succeeded 1 failed. Here is the error log.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Checking Build System
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: catch, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: Continuous, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
4>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: Experimental, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
5>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: Nightly, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
5>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
6>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: NightlyMemoryCheck, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
6>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
7>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: RUN_TESTS, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
7>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
2>Creating directories for 'catch'
2>Building Custom Rule C:/SWALEH_WORK_FILES/THIS_WILL_WORK/araas/thirdparty/cppzmq/tests/CMakeLists.txt
2>Performing download step (download and verify) for 'catch'
2>-- File already exists but no hash specified (use URL_HASH):
2>  file='C:/SWALEH_WORK_FILES/THIS_WILL_WORK/araas/thirdparty/cppzmq/Build/catch/src/catch.hpp'
2>Old file will be removed and new file downloaded from URL.
2>-- Downloading...
2>   dst='C:/SWALEH_WORK_FILES/THIS_WILL_WORK/araas/thirdparty/cppzmq/Build/catch/src/catch.hpp'
2>   timeout='none'
2>-- Using src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/catchorg/Catch2/Catch1.x/single_include/catch.hpp'
2>-- [download 0% complete]
2>-- [download 1% complete]
2>-- [download 2% complete]
2>-- [download 3% complete]
2>-- [download 4% complete]
2>-- [download 5% complete]
2>-- [download 6% complete]
2>-- [download 7% complete]
2>-- [download 8% complete]
2>-- [download 9% complete]
2>-- [download 10% complete]
2>-- [download 11% complete]
2>-- [download 12% complete]
2>-- [download 13% complete]
2>-- [download 14% complete]
2>-- [download 15% complete]
2>-- [download 16% complete]
2>-- [download 17% complete]
2>-- [download 18% complete]
2>-- [download 19% complete]
2>-- [download 20% complete]
2>-- [download 21% complete]
2>-- [download 22% complete]
2>-- [download 23% complete]
2>-- [download 24% complete]
2>-- [download 25% complete]
2>-- [download 26% complete]
2>-- [download 27% complete]
2>-- [download 28% complete]
2>-- [download 29% complete]
2>-- [download 30% complete]
2>-- [download 31% complete]
2>-- [download 32% complete]
2>-- [download 33% complete]
2>-- [download 34% complete]
2>-- [download 35% complete]
2>-- [download 36% complete]
2>-- [download 37% complete]
2>-- [download 38% complete]
2>-- [download 39% complete]
2>-- [download 40% complete]
2>-- [download 41% complete]
2>-- [download 42% complete]
2>-- [download 43% complete]
2>-- [download 44% complete]
2>-- [download 45% complete]
2>-- [download 46% complete]
2>-- [download 47% complete]
2>-- [download 48% complete]
2>-- [download 49% complete]
2>-- [download 50% complete]
2>-- [download 51% complete]
2>-- [download 52% complete]
2>-- [download 53% complete]
2>-- [download 54% complete]
2>-- [download 55% complete]
2>-- [download 56% complete]
2>-- [download 57% complete]
2>-- [download 58% complete]
2>-- [download 59% complete]
2>-- [download 60% complete]
2>-- [download 61% complete]
2>-- [download 62% complete]
2>-- [download 63% complete]
2>-- [download 64% complete]
2>-- [download 65% complete]
2>-- [download 66% complete]
2>-- [download 67% complete]
2>-- [download 68% complete]
2>-- [download 69% complete]
2>-- [download 70% complete]
2>-- [download 71% complete]
2>-- [download 72% complete]
2>-- [download 73% complete]
2>-- [download 74% complete]
2>-- [download 75% complete]
2>-- [download 76% complete]
2>-- [download 77% complete]
2>-- [download 78% complete]
2>-- [download 79% complete]
2>-- [download 80% complete]
2>-- [download 81% complete]
2>-- [download 82% complete]
2>-- [download 83% complete]
2>-- [download 84% complete]
2>-- [download 85% complete]
2>-- [download 86% complete]
2>-- [download 87% complete]
2>-- [download 88% complete]
2>-- [download 89% complete]
2>-- [download 90% complete]
2>-- [download 91% complete]
2>-- [download 92% complete]
2>-- [download 93% complete]
2>-- [download 94% complete]
2>-- [download 95% complete]
2>-- [download 96% complete]
2>-- [download 97% complete]
2>-- [download 98% complete]
2>-- [download 99% complete]
2>-- [download 100% complete]
2>-- Downloading... done
2>No update step for 'catch'
2>No patch step for 'catch'
2>No configure step for 'catch'
2>No build step for 'catch'
2>No install step for 'catch'
2>No test step for 'catch'
2>Completed 'catch'
8>------ Rebuild All started: Project: unit_tests, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
8>Building Custom Rule C:/SWALEH_WORK_FILES/THIS_WILL_WORK/araas/thirdparty/cppzmq/tests/CMakeLists.txt
8>buffer.cpp
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C3646: 'fd': unknown override specifier
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2523): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'zmq::poller_event<T>' being compiled
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\tests\buffer.cpp(19,5): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8>message.cpp
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\Build\catch\src\catch.hpp(6902,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C3646: 'fd': unknown override specifier
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2523): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'zmq::poller_event<T>' being compiled
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8>context.cpp
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C3646: 'fd': unknown override specifier
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2523): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'zmq::poller_event<T>' being compiled
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\tests\context.cpp(18,5): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8>socket.cpp
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C3646: 'fd': unknown override specifier
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2523): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'zmq::poller_event<T>' being compiled
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\ppltasks.h(1571,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8>socket_ref.cpp
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C3646: 'fd': unknown override specifier
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2523): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'zmq::poller_event<T>' being compiled
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\tests\socket_ref.cpp(16,5): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8>poller.cpp
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C3646: 'fd': unknown override specifier
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2523): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'zmq::poller_event<T>' being compiled
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\tests\testutil.hpp(27,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\tests\poller.cpp(11,42): error C2338:
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\tests\poller.cpp(12,42): error C2338:
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\tests\poller.cpp(14,42): error C2338:
8>active_poller.cpp
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C3646: 'fd': unknown override specifier
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2523): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'zmq::poller_event<T>' being compiled
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq_addon.hpp(680,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8>multipart.cpp
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C3646: 'fd': unknown override specifier
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2523): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'zmq::poller_event<T>' being compiled
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq_addon.hpp(680,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8>recv_multipart.cpp
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C3646: 'fd': unknown override specifier
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2523): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'zmq::poller_event<T>' being compiled
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq_addon.hpp(680,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8>send_multipart.cpp
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C3646: 'fd': unknown override specifier
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2523): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'zmq::poller_event<T>' being compiled
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq_addon.hpp(680,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8>codec_multipart.cpp
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C3646: 'fd': unknown override specifier
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2523): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'zmq::poller_event<T>' being compiled
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq_addon.hpp(680,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8>monitor.cpp
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C3646: 'fd': unknown override specifier
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2523): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'zmq::poller_event<T>' being compiled
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\tests\testutil.hpp(27,1): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8>utilities.cpp
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C3646: 'fd': unknown override specifier
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2523): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'zmq::poller_event<T>' being compiled
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\zmq.hpp(2517,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
8>C:\SWALEH_WORK_FILES\THIS_WILL_WORK\araas\thirdparty\cppzmq\tests\utilities.cpp(92,5): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8>Generating Code...
8>Done building project "unit_tests.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
9>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
9>Building Custom Rule C:/SWALEH_WORK_FILES/THIS_WILL_WORK/araas/thirdparty/cppzmq/CMakeLists.txt
10>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
10>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Rebuild All: 3 succeeded, 1 failed, 6 skipped ==========
```

When I try to build with cmake, I get the following error:
[image]

I can't find any generated dll files in the Build directory. I am not sure what I need to do to generate these files. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, do not add images of logs or code, but add them as **text** instead.

Comment: cppzmq is a header-only library. Nothing needs to be built, and there is no cppzmq DLL or library file. The cmake files are only needed for building & running the cppzmq tests. While that doesn't solve the reported issue, it doesn't block you from using cppzmq.